# How to connect raspberry pi to another PC's database using python

Tags: python, mysql, database, raspberry-pi

I have a database in my current RPI. Since I'm only using 64GB SD card, I want to remove the database in my rpi and connect it to database of my laptop.

I've setup my LAN, I can now access the database through browser using my IP (192.168.1.14) but my code is not working.

Can you guys help me on how to connect my python code to another database.

here's my code to connect to database

```
import tkinter as tk
import pymysql
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class Kiosk(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
       self.master = master
       master.title("Thesis")

       self.login_button = Button(master, text = "Login", bg= "white")
       self.login_button.pack()
       self.register_button = Button(master, text="Register", command=self.register)
       self.register_button.pack()

       self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.destroy)
       self.close_button.pack()
       self.reader = SimpleMFRC522()

       self.master.configure(bg="white")    
       self.ws = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
       self.hs = self.master.winfo_screenheight()

       self.master.geometry("{}x{}".format(self.ws, self.hs))

       self.db = pymysql.connect(host = "192.168.1.14", port = 3306, user = "root",passwd = "",db= "Thesis")
       self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
       self.QueryResident = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS residence (FIRST_NAME varchar(255) not null, MIDDLE_NAME varchar(255) not null, LAST_NAME varchar(255) not null,SEX varchar(255) not null, BIRTH_DATE date, CIVIL_STATUS varchar(255) not null, PLACE_OF_BIRTH varchar(255) not null, RFID varchar(255))"
       self.cursor.execute(self.QueryResident)
       GPIO.cleanup()

   def registered(self, first_name, middle_name, last_name, sex, birth_day, civil_status, place_of_birth):
       self.get_first_name = self.first_name.get()
       self.get_middle_name = self.middle_name.get()
       self.get_last_name = self.last_name.get()
       self.get_sex = self.sex.get()
       self.get_birth_day = self.birth_day.get()
       self.get_civil_status = self.civil_status.get()
       self.get_place_of_birth = self.place_of_birth.get()


       if (self.get_first_name == "" or self.get_middle_name == "" or
           self.get_last_name == "" or self.get_sex == "" or self.get_birth_day == "" or
           self.get_civil_status == "" or self.get_place_of_birth == ""):
               messagebox.showerror("Error!","Please complete the required field", parent = self.master_register)
       else:
           self.master_register.destroy()
           self.RFID_registered()

   def RFID_registered(self):
       if (self.cursor.fetchone() is not None):
           messagebox.showerror("Notice!", "RFID card is already registered", parent = self.master_register)
       else:
           messagebox.showinfo("Success!","Your Registration is Successful", parent = self.master_register)
           self.cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO residence (FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, SEX, BIRTH_DATE, CIVIL_STATUS, PLACE_OF_BIRTH) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(self.get_first_name,
                                                                                                                                                                                          self.get_middle_name,
                                                                                                                                                                                          self.get_last_name,
                                                                                                                                                                                          self.get_sex,
                                                                                                                                                                                          self.get_birth_day,
                                                                                                                                                                                          self.get_civil_status,
                                                                                                                                                                                          self.get_place_of_birth,
                                                                                                                                                                                          ))
           self.db.commit()
           self.master_register.destroy()
           GPIO.cleanup()

       GPIO.cleanup()


   def only_numeric_input(self, P):
       if P.isdigit() or P == "":
           return True
       return False

   def register(self):
       self.master_register = Toplevel()


       self.first_name = StringVar()
       self.middle_name = StringVar()
       self.last_name = StringVar()
       self.sex = StringVar()
       self.birth_day = StringVar()
       self.civil_status = StringVar()
       self.place_of_birth = StringVar()

       self.label_head = Label(self.master_register, text = "Please fill up all informations below",bg = "white")
       self.label_head.pack()

       self.label_first_name = Label(self.master_register, text = "First Name",bg = "white")
       self.label_first_name.pack()
       self.entry_first_name = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.first_name,bg = "white")
       self.entry_first_name.pack()

       self.label_middle_name = Label(self.master_register, text = "Middle Name",bg = "white")
       self.label_middle_name.pack()
       self.entry_middle_name = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.middle_name,bg = "white")
       self.entry_middle_name.pack()

       self.label_last_name = Label(self.master_register, text = "Last Name",bg = "white")
       self.label_last_name.pack()
       self.entry_last_name = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.last_name,bg = "white")
       self.entry_last_name.pack()

       self.label_sex = Label(self.master_register, text = "Sex",bg = "white")
       self.label_sex.pack()
       self.radio_button_sex = Radiobutton(self.master_register, text = "Male", variable = self.sex, value = "Male",bg = "white")
       self.radio_button_sex.pack()
       self.radio_button_sex = Radiobutton(self.master_register, text = "Female", variable = self.sex, value = "Female",bg = "white")
       self.radio_button_sex.pack()

       self.label_birth_day = Label(self.master_register, text = "Birth Day",bg = "white")
       self.label_birth_day.pack()

       self.entry_birth_day = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.birth_day,bg = "white")
       self.entry_birth_day.pack()
       self.callback = self.master_register.register(self.only_numeric_input)
       self.entry_birth_day.configure(validate = "key", validatecommand = (self.callback, "%P"))

       self.label_civil_status = Label(self.master_register, text = "Civil Status",bg = "white")
       self.label_civil_status.pack()
       self.entry_civil_status = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.civil_status,bg = "white")
       self.entry_civil_status.pack()

       self.label_place_of_birth = Label(self.master_register, text = "Place of Birth",bg = "white")
       self.label_place_of_birth.pack()
       self.entry_place_of_birth = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.place_of_birth,bg = "white")
       self.entry_place_of_birth.pack()



       self.button_submit = Button(self.master_register, text = "Submit",bg = "white", command = lambda: self.registered(self.first_name, self.middle_name,
                                                                                           self.last_name, self.sex, self.birth_day,
                                                                                           self.civil_status, self.place_of_birth))
       self.button_submit.pack()


if __name__== "__main__":
   root = Tk()
   main = Kiosk(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

```
Here's the error I've encountered.
`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mfrc522/MFRC522.py:151: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(pin_rst, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/stack.py", line 145, in <module>
    main = Kiosk(root)
  File "/home/pi/stack.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.db = pymysql.connect(host = "192.168.1.14", port = 3306, user = "root",passwd = "",db= "Thesis")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 598, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 975, in _get_server_information
    packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 671, in _read_packet
    % (packet_number, self._next_seq_id))
pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 0
```

Hope you guys can help me, Thank you so much!

Comment: We’re probably going to need to see more of your program, both on the RPU and the laptop.

Comment: Hi sir, I don't have a code in my laptop only in RPI.
My code is quite long since I added a GUI but i edited the question now and added the creation of my table. I'm actually new to this so I'm quite clueless. My code is working If i use the database in my RPI. My connection in my RPI is ```self.db = pymysql.connect(host = "raspberrypi", user = "root",passwd = "",db= "thesis")```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what's wrong with your program. However, you can give the below program a shot!

```
import pymysql as db
try:
    con=db.connect("Enter the host here ","user_name","pass_word","db_name")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
con.autocommit(True)
with con:
        cur=con.cursor()
        cur.execute("DROP table if exists Test_Table")
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Test_Table(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(20),Time timestamp,age float(20)")
```

Change the column names accordingly for your requirement!

Comment: Hi sir, 
Thank you for your reply, I'm sorry If I can't clarify my problem and can't put much code. The only thing I need to do is to access the database in another PC and I'm very clueless on how to do it. I've tried searching for the solution, all I can see is to change the `host` to ip address of the server. I did changed it but I got an error. Anyway thank you so much for your answer. It helps me.

Comment: And explain your problem! It is a very easy task . It can be done without any problem!

Comment: I edited my question. I provided my code above and its error. thank you so much

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm dumb in this, I hope you can help me :)

Comment: In addition, I can now access the database of my laptop in RPI browser using the IP address of my laptop.